# WhatsApp using microphone in the background

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, microphone, background-process

Got a notification today that whatsapp is using microphone while not using the phone.

To view it again I got under  settings/lock screen/app permission monitor/permission history and during the day whatsapp used contacts several times.
I am using samsung s7 (sm-g930p), running on android 8.0.0 (august 1 2018 security patch level)

Can someone explain what is happening? Is anyone else experiencing this?[image]

Comment: The contacts are accessed at regular intervals to look for any new numbers that may have joined/left whatsapp. But the microphone thing is really fishy.

Comment: cmon @harpratap, I was crossing my fingers for a good news.. however, I uninstalled/installed and updated it again, now its not requesting the mic anymore. I hope they had a bug and fixed it..

Comment: fixed it like "Android sys can't detect them anymore" lol

Comment: A bit off topic, but how do you reach the permission access history?

Comment: @YoavFeuerstein settings/lock screen/app permission monitor/permission history